# Error in reading json file with schema in Scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Getting error while reading ArrayType values(phoneNumbers), without ArrayType values, I can read rest values.

```
{
    "firstName": "Rack",
    "lastName": "Jackon",
    "gender": "man",
    "age": 24,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": 126,
        "city": "San Jone",
        "state": "CA",
        "postalCode": 394221
    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
        { "type": "home", "number": 7383627627}
    ]
}

My schema ->
val schema=StructType(List(
      StructField("firstName",StringType),
      StructField("lastName",StringType),
      StructField("gender",StringType),
      StructField("age",IntegerType),
      StructField("address",StructType(List(
        StructField("streetAddress",StringType),
        StructField("city",StringType),
        StructField("state",StringType),
        StructField("postalCode",IntegerType)))),
      StructField("phoneNumbers",ArrayType(StructType(List(
      StructField("type",StringType),
      StructField("number",IntegerType))))),
    ))

json_df.selectExpr("firstName","lastName",
      "gender","age","address.streetAddress","address.city",
      "address.state","address.postalCode",
      "explode(phoneNumbers) as phone","phone.type","phone.number").drop("phone").show()
```

When I do `.show`, it shows only column names and no values but when I don't take "phoneNumbers" array, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IntegerType` represents 4-byte signed integer numbers and has a maximum of 2147483647, which cannot hold phone numbers. Either use `LongType` or `StringType` for phone numbers.

You got no results from your `select` query because you're exploding an empty array of phone numbers, which returns 0 rows. The array is empty because the phone numbers cannot be saved in an `IntegerType` column.